# Is there any tool for fuzzy sequence matching?

Tags: proteins, python, blast, software-recommendation

*Note: this question was also asked on [biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/409111/#409142)*

are you aware of any tool that is able to perform error-tolerant pattern-matching search on protein FASTA files?

For example, I want to know, which proteins in my fasta file to match`ADNG..C.G` regexp (which represents `ADNGCG` pattern). However, I want to be tolerant to matching errors, meaning that I'm good with any protein that differs in any 1 letter in the motif: `ADNG..C.D`, `ADNG..D.G`, `MDNG..C.G`, etc are all good. Running all possible variants through `grep` is possible, but exponentially long for longer patterns (I usually have `15-20` letters in pattern, and scan `~10e6-7` sequences).

I am aware of the tool `agrep` ([docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrep). As far as I know, it's not supported anymore, and also does not distinguish letters in which it's allowed to make error. Also, it does not support long enough patterns (with more than 9 errors -- and yes, I tried to recompile it with myself from [here](https://github.com/Wikinaut/agrep) and could not get it work). Also, it's not designed for proteins specifically.

I am also aware of [ScanProsite](https://prosite.expasy.org/scanprosite/) and [Protein Pattern Find](https://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/protein_pattern.html) services. The first one is not error-prone, the second one is seems to be a web interface for `grep`.

Comment: As correctly mentioned on biostars, where I cross-posted it, I should add cross reference to that topic: https://www.biostars.org/p/409111/#409142

Comment: Thanks for the link. I personally have no problem with cross-posting, especially if you're linking to other sites and acknowledging the source of any gained knowledge that's added here.

Comment: Have you tried using `blastp` with input containing IUPAC ambiguous bases, and post-filter results to match your criteria? I'm uncertain how ambiguous bases are treated for proteins, as opposed to nucleotide searches, but that might be an avenue to explore.

Answer (score 2):

Python solution:
e<=2 will allow up to 2 insertions, 2 deletions, or 2 SNPs in any 2 combinations

```
import regex
seq_list=["GGGAGGG", "GGGAAGGG", "GGGAAAGGG", "TTTATTT", "TTTAATTT", "TTTAAATTT", "GGGG", "GGG"]
for sequence in seq_list:
    if regex.search("(GGGGGG|TTTTTT){e<=2}", sequence):
        print(sequence)
```

GGGAGGG
GGGAAGGG
TTTATTT
TTTAATTT
GGGG

Can also include a wildcard

```
seq_list=["GGGAAAAAGGG", "GGGAAAAATGG", "GGGAAAAATTG", "GGGAAAAATTT"]
for sequence in seq_list:
    if regex.search("(GGG.*GGG|TTTTTT){e<=2}", sequence):
        print(sequence)
```

GGGAAAAAGGG
GGGAAAAATGG
GGGAAAAATTG

Comment: Agreed on the approach, it can be solved with an outer loop forcing s floating wildcard [AGTC] or [A-Z]  across the regex search term

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
The problem is, it is unadequately slow -- e.g. matching whole uniprot with that is very slow. 

Also, I am not aware of it's computational complexity for python regex fuzzy matching -- are you aware of its description?